# Render selected item outside of input box for multi select of react-select library

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How can we display the selected value just below the input box.

Use Case:

We are using multiple select of react-select , when we select the value from the select box , it comes inside the input box as selected. Can we have a method or something to get the selected values outside the input box (just below it)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I solved it creating a wrapper of react-select component and adding a state to my custom component. When the react-select changes I added the selected items to my component state and I show the in a custom div below, there you can add the styles that you want. Here an example of my approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/2kyy4998y

Hope this helps you.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do this for a project I'm working on and wrote up how I did it [here](https://prepsheets.com/tech-blog/react-select-with-options-outside). The gist is that you need a wrapper component

```js
// SelectWrapper.js
import ReactSelect from 'react-select'

const SelectWrapper = (props) => {
    const { isMulti, value } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {isMulti ? value.map((val) => <span>{val.label}</span>) : null}
            <Select {...props} controlShouldRenderValue={!isMulti} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The very important part here is the `controlShouldRenderValue` prop which we disable when `isMulti` is true so the select dosn't show any selected values instead letting us take care of that

Comment: link moved? https://dev.to/rbt/react-select-with-options-outside-353g